# How to avoid excessive logging by autoreload in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

currently I am using logging from django rest framework.But I am getting excessive logging by autoreload.

I want to avoid excessive logging of autoreload.

I'm doing this right now

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'file': {
            'format': '{levelname} | {asctime} | {module} | {message} | {funcName} | {lineno} |',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'fileInfo': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': "./info.log",
            'formatter': 'file',
        },
        'fileError': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': "./error.log",
            'formatter': 'file',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['fileInfo', 'fileError'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },

}
```

and in view.py

```
import logging 
logger = logging.getLogger('django')

def addsomething:
    logger.info("print something")
    logger.error("error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to avoid excessive logging by auto reload add this line it will disable the logger

```
LOGGING['loggers']['django.server']['level'] = 'WARNING'
```

and if you want to complete disable the logging

```
LOGGING['loggers']['django.utils.autoreload']['level'] = 'CRITICAL'
```

Comment: where should I add this?

Comment: settings.py file